# Why is there no preposition after the word ‘requires’?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> The constitution requires members of parliament to take an oath of allegiance

I read this sentence in dictionary list of sentence examples and I would like to know: Why is "to" not needed in here:

> "The constitution requires **to** members of parliament to take an oath of allegiance"

or:

> "The constitution requires **toward**  members of parliament to take an oath of allegiance."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I hit my thumb **with** a hammer.

In the above sentence, The object of the verb **hit** is **my thumb**. No preposition is required for the object. We use the preposition **with** to provide additional information about what is happening... **with a hammer**.

With verbs like **need** and **require**, the object is the thing that's required: there is no need for a preposition, as the thing that's needed is the object if the verb- it's not additional information.

> I need **a hammer**

If what's required is an action, we use as the object a noun phrase which contains the noun form of a verb (a to-infinitive or gerund) or a noun with the same meaning as the verb.

> I need **to buy some new shoes** - *to-infinitive*
>   My watch needs **repairing** - *gerund*
>   My dog needs **a walk** - *noun*

So, before a verb, **to** is not a preposition: it is an infinitive marker.

If the subject of the verb is the same as the subject of **need**, as in **to buy some new shoes** above, it is omitted. If the subject is different, it is placed between **needs** and the to-infinitive.

> The constitution requires members of parliament **to** take an oath of allegiance

Looking at your sentence, **to** is already present as an infinitive marker before the verb (take). The verb (a to-infinitive) appears in its normal place in the noun-phrase, between the subject **members of parliament** and the object **an oath of allegiance**.

Comment: > The constitution members of parliament **have to** take an oath of allegiance.

> The constitution requires members of parliament **to** take an oath of allegiance.

thanks, And I woud also like to know, Is this sentences same meaning?  @JavaLatte

Comment: No, that sentence is not correct. You can't put two subjects **the constitution** and **members of parliament** in front of a verb. The difference is that, with **require**, the subject is the person or thing that **makes** somebody do something, and with **have to** the subject is the person of thing that is being **made** to do something.